# Regressão Linear em Vários Produtos

Tags: python, regressão

Rodei uma regressão simples para uma base de dados com um produto (Produto, Volume, Preço). Rodou perfeitamente. 
Mas gostaria de rodar a mesma regressão em uma base com mais produtos, porém, quero poder escolher o produto que quero rodar a regressão, veja:

ex.

> ```
> Produto | Volume | Preço
>
> A
>
> A         
>
> B
>
> B
> ```

Quero rodar a regressão apenas no produto B.

- Como fazer isso?
- Como Rodar a regressão em todos os produtos, porém, retornar separadamente, de modo que eu possa analisá-los um ao lado do outro?

Cód.

```
import pandas as pd

Pasta1 = pd.ExcelFile ('Pasta2.xlsx')
Daniel = pd.read_excel (Pasta1, 'Tela')


from scipy.stats import linregress

x= Daniel ['Preço']
y= Daniel ['Volume'] 
m, b, R, p, SEm = linregress (x, y)

pd.DataFrame ([m , b, R, p, SEm] , columns=['Valores'] , index=['declive', 
'ordenada_na_origem', 'coeficiente_de_correlação_(de_Pearson)', 'p-value', 
'erro_padrão'])
```

Resultado:

```
Valores

declive: 421.398071 

ordenada_na_origem: 1432.443189 

coeficiente_de_correlação_(de_Pearson): 0.331966 

p-value: 0.000003 

erro_padrão: 86.869651
```

Comment: Ok Guto... Vou tentar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dado o que me parece ser o seus dados, eu consegui resolver usando o atributo [`.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) do dataframe do pandas.

Um exemplo de como fiz:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6,4),index=list('abadaf'),columns=list('ABCD'))
>>df1
          A         B         C         D
a -0.973031  0.305699  1.330237 -0.799858
b -0.879060  0.238690 -2.729635 -0.457865
a -2.001388  1.058163 -0.328737  0.134416
d  0.994644 -2.305340 -0.714434  0.298462
a -2.242108 -0.331434  0.969981  0.973202
f -0.483833  0.783812  0.925608  0.590251

>>df1.loc['a']
          A         B         C         D
a -0.973031  0.305699  1.330237 -0.799858
a -2.001388  1.058163 -0.328737  0.134416
a -2.242108 -0.331434  0.969981  0.973202

>> df1.loc['a','A']
a   -0.973031
a   -2.001388
a   -2.242108
```

Aqui o "nome do produto" está como `index`. Caso você queira chamar os dados baseados em seus valores(strings ou números), você pode usar o `.loc` juntamente com [expressões bolleanas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#selection-by-callable) :

```
>> df1 = pd.DataFrame([['a',1,2,3],['b',2,3,4],['a',3,4,5],['c',4,5,6]],index=list('defg'),columns=list('higj'))
>> df1
   h  i  g  j
d  a  1  2  3
e  b  2  3  4
f  a  3  4  5
g  c  4  5  6

>> df1.h=='a'
d     True
e    False
f     True
g    False
Name: h, dtype: bool
>> df1.loc[ df1.h=='a',:]
   h  i  g  j
d  a  1  2  3
f  a  3  4  5
>> df1.loc[ df1.h=='a','i']
d    1
f    3
```

Comment: Guto, usando o .loc a busca só acontece no Index? Se (a,b,c,d,e,f) constasse em uma coluna (como se fossem produtos) eu conseguiria, por exemplo, plotar um gráfico apenas com o produto A? Ou então, como eu havia colocado no exemplo, consigo fazer uma regressão usando o volume e o preço do produto A?

Comment: Guto, muito obrigado pela ajuda. Com a tua dica eu consegui.

Comment: Certo, é no só clicar no flag?

Comment: A poprósito Guto, eu preciso de um jeito de não precisar repetir cada bloco de cada produto, isso é possível?

Comment: @DanielMelo, vou dar uma olhada quando der, acho que dá pra fazer de maneira simples, mas tenho que testar. BTW, repare que removi os comentários que não são mais relevantes. Assim a pergunta fica mais limpa para futuras referências.

Comment: Tá... Eu sou novo por aqui, então ainda não sei mexer muito bem... obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

Com a ajuda do Guto, resolvi da seguinte forma:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Pasta1 = pd.ExcelFile ('Pasta2.xlsx')
Daniel = pd.read_excel (Pasta1, 'Tela')


from scipy.stats import linregress

x= Daniel.loc [(Daniel ['Preço'] > 0) & (Daniel ['Produto'] == 'A')]
x1= x ['Preço']
y= Daniel.loc [(Daniel ['Volume'] > 0) & (Daniel ['Produto'] == 'A')]
y1= y ['Volume']
Produto_A = linregress (x1, y1)


x2= Daniel.loc [(Daniel ['Preço'] > 0) & (Daniel ['Produto'] == 'B')]
x3= x2 ['Preço']
y2= Daniel.loc [(Daniel ['Volume'] > 0) & (Daniel ['Produto'] == 'B')]
y3= y2 ['Volume']
Produto_B = linregress (x3, y3)


pd.DataFrame ([Produto_A, Produto_B] , index=['Valores', 'Valores2'])
```

Agora só preciso encontar um jeito de rodar com mais produtos, sem a necessidade de criar um bloco para cada produto.